# Jquery Date picker shows different day on phone vs PC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, mobile, datepicker

I am baffled by this current situation.

My PC Shows the Jquery date picker properly. Where as accessing the same webpage from the phone shows the date pickers days as offset by 1.

I.e.

```
10/4/2012 = Tuesday on PC. 
10/4/2012 = Monday on phone.
```

Things I have checked:

- Both say April 2012 along the top.
- The Date and time is set correctly on the
  phone.
- Both are using GMT London time.
- Both are running from the same
  page, hence same code.

Comment: What is the phone? Does it also say it's Monday (outside of any web page)?

Comment: Yep, it knows today is Monday outside of the webpage. Its a blackberry 9860.

Comment: I'm pretty sure today is Tuesday... at least it is in England!

Comment: Also, England is currently using British Summer Time (BST) instead of GMT, not sure if this makes a difference?

Comment: its on my localhost. Sorry I ment tuesday lol. Phone is mixing me up.

Comment: Right now is Tuesday regardless of DST

Comment: Tell that to the date picker ;)

Comment: Also look [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/) & [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)

Comment: Ive tried viewing this on other phones and it works fine. Its just this blackberry (and possibly all blackberries)

Answer (score 0):

This is because javascript is client-side not server-side.

So it takes the device date.

Comment: I am aware of that thanks. Like I said in my question though, the device date is set correctly. and the dates are exactly the same .. yet one thinks its monday, and the other says tuesday.